# How do I create the Spirit Phase Walk effect in Dead by Daylight?

Tags: unity

I am wondering how do I create the Spirit's phase walk effect from Dead by Daylight in Unity?

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-HLfNwIg4Q) demonstrates the effect I'm trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the character just teleports around randomly while chasing. Once the spirit stops teleporting around they resume the chase and face the player again, running towards the player
Then it looks like it's just rendering as transparent geometry, fading out as it shifts around.

Comment: @Hikari, Just a note: There are many **Unity assets** that provides transparent effects. These assets are available online at **Unity asset store**. They are very easy to use.

Comment: I think i kinda understand what you meant.., thanks for giving me an idea on how to do it. :)